# How do I choose the optimal parameters for reliefF

Tags: feature-selection, hyperparameter, parameter-estimation

For feature selection I use reliefF provided by matlab.
The reliefF function offers a parameter k to influence its ouput, additionaly for my specific task I can also vary a window length l on which the features are computed. ( I am classifying sensor signals )
My question is how do I choose the optimal parameters **k** and **l** ?

Especially how should I score the different parameter configurations ?
Can I use the weights outputed by reliefF ( average weights of all features ) ? I dont't want to use classification error based on the selected features, since then an other question arises : Which classifier should be used, and how are its hyperparameters selected ?